# Serialization of Chart configuration in Vaadin

Tags: java, json, serialization, charts, vaadin

I use Vaadin 7. I want to save a Chart configuration and restore it later. I found an interesting thing in `com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.Configuration` is that you can serialize the configuration into JSON object.

Code :

```
chart.getConfiguration().toString();
```

Result:

```
{
    "type": "column"
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "Chart"
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": [
      "f",
      "e"
    ],
    "axisIndex": 0
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "min": 0,
    "title": {
      "text": "Quantity"
    },
    "axisIndex": 0
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "_fn_formatter": "this.series.name +\u0027: \u0027+ this.y +\u0027 (\u0027+ Math.round(this.percentage) +\u0027%)\u0027"
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "column": {
      "stacking": "normal"
    }
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "data": [
        1,
        2
      ],
      "name": "d",
      "visible": true
    }
  ],
  "exporting": {
    "enabled": false
  }
}
```

What I want now is build Configuration from that JSON object. Is there a way to that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, pretty simple actually :

```
Chart chart = new Chart();

//json is the string containing your JSON object
chart.setJsonConfig(json);

//you'll have to draw the chart to update it if needed
//chart.drawChart();
```